# Xcode 10.1 Thread 2: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, sigabrt

This open-source iOS project from github https://github.com/tirupati17/currency-converter-swift3.0-viper builds successfully, but it crashes during runtime with a SIGABRT error, before the simulator can populate the tableview. There's no place in the code that is highlighted in red to lead me to the source of the error. Instead, it crashes and lands on some [memory address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP5K2.png) as shown in the image. At the bottom of the error log it shows that an 'NSNull' value can't be cast to 'NSDictionary'.

I tried using a [bactrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7daJ1.jpg), but I don't know how to locate the line of code that is causing the error. Other SO answers mention misspelled IBOutlets and actually highlight some line of code where the error occurs, unlike in this case.

How can I locate the line of code where a possible forced-unwrapping of an optional is taking place? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code that populates the table view. How did you set up the table view?

Comment: The code is from someone else. I just found it on github as a practice app. If I were to guess how the tableview is set up, I can give two links 1) https://github.com/tirupati17/currency-converter-swift3.0-viper/blob/master/CurrencyConverter/Classes/Modules/Converter/View/ConverterView.swift 2) https://github.com/tirupati17/currency-converter-swift3.0-viper/blob/master/CurrencyConverter/Classes/Modules/CurrencyList/View/CurrencyListView.swift You may try cloning it to get a better idea. I'm just trying to set random breakpoints and stepping through functions, but assembly code makes it hard.